# Create inclined chart labels on stacked bar charts

Tags: labeling, charts

Ive hunted high and low for a solution. I can put inclined labels on bar charts:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"c1", "c2"}, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]}]
```

, but this fails for stacks:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4,5,6}},
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"a", "b"}, Axis, 
    Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To associate `labels` with rows of data you need to use `ChartLabels -> {labels, None}`.

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"aaa", "bbb"}, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &], None}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]