# How can I dynamically label Bar charts

Tags: labeling, charts

I found the following labeling code (by @Brett) and like to use it as an example:

```
Module[{
    labels = {"ABC Learning focused", "DEF Positively oriented",
    "GHI Continuous", "KLM Timely", "NOP Clear criteria", 
    "RST Flexible", "UWZ Suited to student level"}, 
data = {8, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9}
}, 
BarChart[data, 
    ChartLabels -> Placed[
        labels, 
        Axis, 
        Block[{text = Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi]}, 
            Row[{text, Invisible[text]}, 
                "\[NegativeMediumSpace]"]
        ]&
        ], 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, Ticks -> {None, Range[0, 10, 2]}, 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {95, 0}}
   ]
]
```

[image]

This `code` would use the labels given in the desired form. My question is how to label the same chart by selecting only the "first 3 letters" (capital or small does not matter) of the existing labels, such as `ABC` as the label for the first bar in the histogram; `DEF` as the second label and so on. In fact, such labeling can be generalized by using a rule such as "select CAPITAL letters` only that appear in a label such as those in this example.

For now, I only want to select the first 3 capital letters.

Comment: `StringTake[#, 3] & /@ labels`

Comment: @Rohit: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. It works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** - Address comment

Don't know what `sectorScores` is, but it works fine with the labels from the question.

```
Module[{labels = {"ABC Learning focused", "DEF Positively oriented", 
    "GHI Continuous", "KLM Timely", "NOP Clear criteria", 
    "RST Flexible", "UWZ Suited to student level"}, 
  data = {8, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9}},
 BarChart[data,
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[StringTake[#, 3] & /@ labels, Axis, 
    Block[{text = Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi]}, 
      Row[{text, Invisible[text]}, "\[NegativeMediumSpace]"]] &],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}},
  Ticks -> {None, Range[0, 10, 2]},
  ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {95, 0}}]]
```

[image]

---

To delete everything except for the capital letters

```
StringReplace[#, Except[CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] -> ""] & /@ labels

(* {"ABCL", "DEFP", "GHIC", "KLMT", "NOPC", "RSTF", "UWZS"} *)
```

Comment: I tried to use your `code` in the following format: `legendsNew = StringTake[#, 3] & /@ sectorScores[[All, 1]];` and  `ChartLabels -> 
 Placed[legendsNew, {{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}, Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi] &],` which uses the entire list of legends for each bar in the chart. In a way, the legends are repearted for each bar, which is not what I want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. I found out the answer to my question (given by @kglr at `https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203157/create-inclined-chart-labels-on-stacked-bar-charts`). Your `code` does not have any problem, but I needed to associate the rows of data with labels and there, @kglr gives the answer and worked for me. Thank you so much.